# Ajax load on a page

Tags: javascript

So, I really like Google play store on web browser.

I am trying to make the similar web behavior.

For example, when you choose a category or item, the menu and overall "frame" of the site does not change (ie. not refreshed) and only the main content changes and a "loading" icon before the content changes.

How can I achieve something like that? is it javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, with JavaScript / Ajax. There are many tutorials and jQuery plugins for this.

Comment: Do you guys know an example or tutorial that I can follow by any chance? or what is it even called ? (what do I search in Google to find more information?)

Comment: As @JonasCz said, just look up Ajax.

Comment: To start with, look at `jQuery.load` documentation, then progress to `jQuery.ajax` for wider application. Also, Google "AJAX" and "`XMLHttpRequest`".

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX, Here are some very good tutorials to get you started.

use jQuery to make it very easy and cross-browser supported

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

> Ajax short for asynchronous JavaScript and
>   XML) is a group of interrelated Web development techniques used on the
>   client-side to create asynchronous Web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Steve, Please refer to the fiddle for simple jQuery.load use:
[jQuery Load](http://jsfiddle.net/LsvpynLo/)

```
$(selector).load('link')
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be achieved by JavaScript/jQuery, css and html. One can use ajax to get data from server and manipulate the data at client side to display it in any part of the page. Here are the links you can refer to:

With plain JavaScript:
[plain JavaScript](http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson18.php)

With jQuery:
[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)